# List.foldr or List.foldl understanding with Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm reading the Elixir docs and I come across this 'foldr' function for the Elixir List module. I'm really having a tough time understanding it. Here is what the doc says:

#### DOCS

```
Folds (reduces) the given list from the right with a function. Requires an accumulator.

iex> List.foldr([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, fn(x, acc) -> x - acc end)
-2
```

So this should return -2. But when I read it, I seem to think that it is trying to minus a number by 0 every time, and if that is the case how do we get -2? I clearly don't understand the accumulator, can someone break it down for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to understand how such functions work is to stick in an `IO.puts` call with all the arguments.

```
iex(1)> List.foldr([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, fn(x, acc) -> IO.puts "#{x} - #{acc} = #{x - acc}"; x - acc end)
4 - 0 = 4
3 - 4 = -1
2 - -1 = 3
1 - 3 = -2
-2
```

So, in the first iteration, `x` is 4 and `acc` is 0, and we get `x - acc = 4 - 0 = 4`. Finally we end up with `-2`.

Answer (score 2):

> Folds (reduces) the given list from the right with a function. Requires an accumulator.

That means that the list is iterated from the right, e. g. the passed function is called 4 times by the following order:

```
fn(4, 0) -> 4 - 0 end
fn(3, 4) -> 3 - 4 end
fn(2, -1) -> 2 + 1 end
fn(1, 3) -> 1 - 3 end
```

Therefore, as a result `-2` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Although both answers already given prefectly answer the question, I would put my own for those coming from OOP background:

Both [`List.foldr/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#foldr/3) and [`List.foldl/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#foldl/3) are simple reducers. In pseudocode (let’s pick up [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) for the sake of clarity), `List.foldl/3` is an exact equivalent of:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(0) { |acc, x| x - acc }
#⇒ 2
```

`List.foldr/3` takes an argument in RtL order, hence we should reverse a list in advance:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reverse.reduce(0) { |acc, x| x - acc }
#⇒ -2
```